# How to use array values in where clause in CodeIgniter

Tags: sql, arrays, codeigniter, loops

I am trying to check array value in where condition.

My try:

```
$con=array('ad_no',$ao);
$this->db->where('ad_no',$con); 
$query = $this->db->get('duration');
$r = $query->result_array();
```

But I got the following error:

> unknown column 'array' in 'where clause'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try a loop:

```
foreach($ad_no as $key=>$id){               
    $this->db->where('ad_no',$id); 
    $query = $this->db->get('duration');
    $r = $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Comment: i am try this also

Comment: $key value set ??

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try like this :

```
$con=array('ad_no' => $ao);
$this->db->where($con); 
$query = $this->db->get('duration');
$r = $query->result_array();
```

I hope this answer can help you and notice me if the code is not run.

Comment: According to the docs, this should be the accepted answer. https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 0):

Try this update batch for collecting data in array instead for hitting query on the loop again n again.

```
$data = array();
foreach($ad_no as $key=>$id){  
  $data[] = array(
   'ad_no' => $id
  );
}
$query = $this->db->update_batch('duration',$data,'ad_no');
```

Answer (score 0):

For using where clause in codeigniter you can do like this also:

```
$data['ad_no'] = $ao; 
$query = $this->db->get_where('duration',$data);
$r = $query->result_array();
```

Your code looks good too.